# Chrome Debug Console not showing Scripts tab for this code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Chrome Debug Console (Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97) is not showing a Scripts tab for this code.  I've got a more complex piece of code I need to debug, however, I've got to get past the Chrome Console issue so I provided this example.  Any help with this would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Draggable objects</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var bMouseUp = true, oDragging, nMouseX, nMouseY, nStartX, nStartY, nZFocus = 100 /* the highest z-Index present 

in     your page plus 1 */;

function dragDown(oPssEvt1) {
var bExit = true, oMsEvent1 = oPssEvt1 || /* IE */ window.event;
for (var iNode = oMsEvent1.target; iNode; iNode = iNode.parentNode) {
if (iNode.className === "draggable") { bExit = false; oDragging = iNode; break; }
}
if (bExit) { return; }
bMouseUp = false;
nStartX = nStartY = 0;
for (var iOffPar = oDragging; iOffPar; iOffPar = iOffPar.offsetParent) {
nStartX += iOffPar.offsetLeft;
nStartY += iOffPar.offsetTop;
}
nMouseX = oMsEvent1.clientX;
nMouseY = oMsEvent1.clientY;
oDragging.style.zIndex = nZFocus++;
return false;
}

function dragMove(oPssEvt2) {
if (bMouseUp) { return; }
var oMsEvent2 = oPssEvt2 || /* IE */ window.event;
oDragging.style.left = String(nStartX + oMsEvent2.clientX - nMouseX) + "px";
oDragging.style.top = String(nStartY + oMsEvent2.clientY - nMouseY) + "px";
}

function dragUp() { bMouseUp = true; }

document.onmousedown = dragDown;
document.onmousemove = dragMove;
document.onmouseup = dragUp;

</script>


<style type="text/css">
.draggable {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: auto;
height: auto;
cursor: move;
}

#myDiv {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
left: 200px;
top: 200px;
background-color: #00ff00;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My chrome version is Version 25.0.1364.5 dev. and in Max osX

so, I just guess, there would be some thing wrong with your HTML-dom structure.
if not, you can open the Tab-"sources" , and choose the file(Sources on the left of the window) to debug.

there are so much mouse events, you may consider the "Remote-debug" on chrome

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging